# How can I make database Mysql accepts numbers in this format (445.795.2 | 301.653.23)

Tags: python

When I try to save my data in database , django shows me an error and I realized that it's about this number format.

Is a returned value from javascript

```
could not convert string to float: '445.795.2'
```

**Even if I set the number in this way... float(445.795.2)**

Comment: Are you in a locale that uses `.` as a thousands separator, as opposed to `,` as is common in the US? In other words, does `445.795.2` mean the same as `445795.2`?

Comment: Have you tryed to use '445795.2'?

Comment: How can I transform it in that way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`445.795.2` isn't a number;

if you meant `4457952`, you can use: `a.replace('.', '')`

if you meant `445795.2`, you can use (it's weird, but it'll work):

```
a = '445.795.2'

mark = 0
for k, v in enumerate(a[::-1]):
    if v == '.':
        mark = k
        break

a = int(a.replace('.', '')) * 10**(-mark)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option if you need to replace all but the last `.` is to count the number of occurrences and then remove all but one.

```
x = '445.795.2'
y = x.count('.')
if y > 1:
    x.replace(".", "", y-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, thats not a number so can't be stored in a number formet.

You need to change the format somehow, either store it as a string, break it into individual columns of numbers (useful if you might be searching on part of the number and its only ever going to be 3 groups of numbers) or into an array which you can put together at the end.

The best option depends upon your circumstances.